# SASM assembly IDE 64 sample compile error "impossible combination of address sizes" on PRINT_STRING msg

Tags: assembly, x86, nasm, sasm

I'm on Windows 7 64-bit and I downloaded the SASM assembly IDE from here:

https://dman95.github.io/SASM/english.html

Several hello world examples are included. The NASM example compiles fine but the NASM 64-bit gives a compile error.

The NASM 64-bit code is:

```
%include "io64.inc"

section .data
    msg db 'Hello, world!', 0

section .text
    global CMAIN
CMAIN:
    mov ebp, esp; for correct debugging
    mov rbp, rsp
    PRINT_STRING msg
    NEWLINE
    xor rax, rax
    ret
```

The compile error is:

```
Build started...
Warning! Errors have occurred in the build:
C:\Temp\SASM\program.asm:11: error: impossible combination of address sizes
C:\Temp\SASM\program.asm:11: error: impossible combination of address sizes
C:\Temp\SASM\program.asm:11: error: impossible combination of address sizes
C:\Temp\SASM\program.asm:12: error: impossible combination of address sizes
C:\Temp\SASM\program.asm:12: error: impossible combination of address sizes
C:\Temp\SASM\program.asm:12: error: impossible combination of address sizes
gcc.exe: error: C:\Temp\SASM\program.o: No such file or directory
```

Why do I get this error/what's happening so I can understand and how do I fix it?

Comment: Obviously the cause of *that* message you put in the title is that NASM didn't create a `.o`, because of the error messages it told you about.  As usual with build scripts, the *first* error is usually the most important, later ones are usually just consequences.

Comment: @PeterCordes I didn't manually port anything. The sample code came with the installation.

Comment: My mistake, I only skimmed that linked page and saw a screenshot of similar 32-bit code including the `mov ebp, esp`.  I assumed no example that came with SASM (or even any attempt at a tutorial) would zero-extend the low 32-bit of the stack pointer into RBP with `mov ebp, esp`, then try again correctly this time with `mov rbp, rsp`, because that's a terrible example.   (Also without saving/restoring RBP.)  If this exact code came with SASM, well I hope the actual IDE is better maintained than the examples.

Comment: The linked docs say `PRINT_STRING` is supposed to work with a bare label name like `msg`, but also with an address expression so maybe worth trying `PRINT_STRING [rel msg]`.  Like I said, to actually figure out why it breaks, you'd have to look at the macro definitions.

Comment: I found https://github.com/Dman95/SASM/blob/master/Windows/Projects/NASMHellox64.asm which looks like your code, except it doesn't have that `mov ebp, esp` line.  Not that it's the problem, but apparently the actual SASM example isn't insane after all.

Answer (score 1):

I got these same error messages when I first tried SASM as an IDE for NASM. The problem is that SASM has two modes, x86 and x64. These modes are set in the Options tab in Settings. The "out of the box" mode setting is x86. To compile the x64 example, you have to select the x64 mode. With x64 checked, the 64-bit example for NASM will assemble and run correctly.